# Why my Hive can not give the result after transform the timestamp?

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I run the code `select  unix_timestamp('2015-07-22 17:34:18')`
the hive returns 1437554058 ;
When I run the code `select from_unixtime(1437554058, 'yyyyMMdd')`
the hive returns '20150722'

But when I run `select from_unixtime( unix_timestamp('2015-07-22 17:34:18'), 'yyyyMMdd')`

there is no error tips and no result return.
So what's wrong with my hive? How to fix it?

Comment: select from_unixtime( unix_timestamp('2015-07-22 17:34:18'), 'yyyyMMdd')  works just fine for me.

Comment: It should work without any issue, for more debugging please share hive logs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happened when trying the code:

```
hive> select from_unixtime( unix_timestamp('2015-07-22 17:34:18'), 'yyyyMMdd')
    > ;
OK
20150722
Time taken: 1.48 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Honestly, my best guess at this point is that you forgot the semicolon.

Comment: without semicolon query will not run in hive cli.

Comment: @SathiyanS Which, in my experience, is the most common cause of the described symptoms.

Comment: @yanachen but does the command actually run? Do you see the OK message?